# ViM-LaTeX, python, and Mac OS 10.8.1 and a weird error

Tags: python, macos, vim, latex

I just updated my machine to Mountain Lion (10.8.1) and am trying to install vim-latex. I have used the suite daily for about 5 years now, but when trying to do a clean install and opening up a .tex file I get the following error message.

```
"UnitCircleAnalysis.tex" 118L, 4154CTraceback (most recent call last):
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 565,
in File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 547,
in main File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278,
in addusersitepackages File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253,
in getusersitepackages File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243,
in getuserbase File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 523,
in get_config_var File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 419,
in get_config_vars File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 298,
in _init_posix IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)
```

This appears to be a problem with the Python implementation. Are there any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Please format the error neatly in a `code` block to make it more readable

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345934/problem-running-python-from-crontab-invalid-python-installation

Comment: I'm going to download and install xcode to see if that fixes the issue. Sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: I don't see any answer where you posted. I cross posted because I am not sure if this is an error in Python or in ViM-LaTeX.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't see why this is off topic, nor was there an answer at the link you provided. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Conner the point is not to repost the same Question to different Stack Exchange sites. That's the point.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I agree but this is the appropriate place for this question. The alternate question should be handled by the LaTeX moderators and the user should be educated to not cross-post. I appreciate your consideration.

Comment: I have solved the situation by installing XCode and the Command Line Tools. This was apparently the correct forum, as it was a Python issue and not a LaTeX issue.

Comment: @jason.t.stein You should add that as an answer and not a comment. Comments are meant to clarify the post, not to answer it.