# When I try to run vim in command line I get Python errors

Tags: python, vim, terminal

When I try running vim in the Terminal (so as to follow [@romainl's suggestion in my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438459/1622940)) I get lots of Python errors, which all boil down to:

```
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)
```

Why is this? I can use Python or Sublime Text even, without any problems.

The full list of errors is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 565, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 547, in main
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 278, in addusersitepackages
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 253, in getusersitepackages
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 243, in getuserbase
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 523, in get_config_var
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 419, in get_config_vars
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 298, in _init_posix
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)
```

**Extra info:**
I am on Mac OS X Mountain Lion (OS 10.8)

**EDIT:**
I tried @BobDunakey idea with no success, the idea was to use `sudo`. I still get the same errors.

**EDIT 2:**
I was able to solve the problem thanks to Zirak's solution, which is the following: http://clearfix.be/2012/08/05/fix-mountain-lion-10-8-python-ioerror-pyconfig-h-error/

Comment: Does this solve it? http://clearfix.be/2012/08/05/fix-mountain-lion-10-8-python-ioerror-pyconfig-h-error/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just had the exact IOError while installing [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) on my dev machine...

This fixes the problem:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/include/python2.7
$ sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h
```

Taken [from here](https://gist.github.com/3186381).

Comment: Awesome, this fixed the problem for me too. I got errors after upgrading to mountain lion

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

find the package that installed it with:

```
dpkg -S /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h
```

Then reinstall the package:

```
apt-get install --reinstall <package name>
```

If that doesn't work download the package @:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/amd64/python2.7-minimal/download

and manually install them with:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i python2.7-minimal_2.7.2-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

2ND EDIT:

Another user here had the same issue:

[ViM-LaTeX, python, and Mac OS 10.8.1 and a weird error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152113/vim-latex-python-and-mac-os-10-8-1-and-a-weird-error)

seemed to fix it buy installing Xcode and the command line tools.

Worth a shot imo.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have `dpkg`, also, I already made sure that I have Python updated, I just updated it through `brew`.

Comment: I already have Xcode installed, and last time I checked I can't get the command line tools for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the default Vim (`/usr/bin/vim`). You should use MacVim's CLI executable instead: `$ /path/to/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/vim`.

MacVim comes with a `mvim` script. Put it somewhere in your `$PATH` and simply do `$ mvim -v`.

Comment: I was using `vim`, I tried `mvim -v` and it worked, I already had `mvim` installed. Although my problem was solved using @Zirak's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem thanks to Zirak's solution, which is the following: http://clearfix.be/2012/08/05/fix-mountain-lion-10-8-python-ioerror-pyconfig-h-error/

Sorry guys for accepting this one, but since neither of your solutions solved it for me, and Zirak's is a comment, I decided to answer the question myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

trying to run 'kodi' (xbmc) #output: /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h (No such file or directory)

$ ls `which python` -l
 # -rwxrwxr-x 1 someone1 someone1 2993744 Dec  2 11:40 /home/someone1/bin/python

$ mv /home/someone1/bin/python /home/someone1/bin/python1

$ which python #output: /usr/bin/python

## now it works !